# Writing Drivers in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, windows, driver, c++builder, c++builder-xe3

How can I write drivers for Windows with the new XE3 64 Bit compiler that just arrived few days ago. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely it's not possible. Even if you succeed somehow to compile the code, it will most likely violate a whole bunch of kernel rules and result in nasty things such as crashes and freezes.

Don't do it. Use only the WDK compiler provided by MS for driver development (it's integrated into VS starting with VS2012).